# sort_by with subquery taking too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, optimization

I'm trying to optimize the queries rendered from this RoR code:

`records.sort_by { |r| r.badge_instances.count }.reverse.each do |s|`

This results in N+1 queries, since for every `record`, there needs to be a `COUNT` gotten for the sort.

Just to clarify, `badge_instance` are children to `record`.  What rails methods can I use to render one query that gets all the badge instance counts, and keeps the counts associated to each `record` for a sort?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've optimized this quite a bit just by adding an index to the foreign key in my BadgeInstance table, but I'm sure a problem will arise again once the data becomes big enough.  Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do one query when you fetch records, then use `size` rather than `count` to prevent the N+1 queries:

```
records = Record.include(:badge_instances).where(...)

records.sort_by { |r| r.badge_instances.size }.reverse.each do |s|
  ...
end
```

In conversing with @MrYoshiji, if either of these tables becomes extremely large, then this could become quite a memory hog (as all of the instances of these objects will be loaded into memory.  In this case, an alternative could be to include a count of the associated records as an attribute within the query:

```
records = Record.select("records.*, COUNT(badge_instances.id) as badge_instances_count").joins(:badge_instances).group("records.id")
```

You will then have access to an attribute on each of the `records` called `badge_instances_count` which you can use to sort the records by the size of the count.  Note that `badge_instances_count` will be a string, so it will need to be converted to an integer for sorting by actual count.

Comment: This is kind of bad: you will actually transform every `badge_instance` record from the DB to a BadgeInstance's instance (ruby object), only then you'll count the size of the array. In this case there is no need to get `badge_instance` records as Ruby instanciated objects since we only want to COUNT them.

Comment: I fail to see how it's different than your comment on the OP's question.  When run through the app, it will work identical to what you suggest in your comment, as your code does essentially the same as the above, does it not?

Comment: I does not, calling `.size` on a ActiveRecord::Relation object is like calling `.size` of Array. `.count` on a ActiveRecord::Relation object actually triggers a SQL count.

Comment: Correct.  And since the `includes(:badge_instances)` eager loads the `BadgeInstance` objects with their corresponding `Record`, a call of `.size` will count the size of the array, preventing the N+1 queries.  As you say, if I use `.count`, N+1 queries will occur.

Comment: That is surprisingly correct, I feel bad now :/ thanks for the clarification and the lesson, @CDub!

Comment: @MrYoshiji no problem dude! :)  You kept me on my toes there for a minute... ;-)  I believe you are correct about this loading all of those instances into memory.  If the number of `Record` objects or `BadgeInstance` objects gets extremely large, this could become a memory hog...

Comment: I would love to get back my SQL abilities and write from my memory the SQL query to do the group_by directly at the DB level ...

Comment: Done in my post.  I'd love another pair of eyes, if you wouldn't mind @MrYoshiji.

Comment: That seems to be correct, I tried it in my console with another has_many relation and it returns coherent results. HUGE +1 for this one!

Comment: It took only ~150ms to run this query for 80 parent records and 22400 child records

Comment: Locally, I did this for 288 parent records 1481 child records, and it took 4ms. :)

Comment: Great answers guys.  Thanks to you all, I've sped up the transaction time for my company.